# how can I send/copy/move the code in /var/www/html

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have setup a git repository in an aws instance. I mounted a volume and set up a git repository there. I have a website in `/var/www/html` (Different volume mounted on same instance) where my websites actual code resides. After I commit git repository it goes in the repository.

How can I send/copy/move the code in `/var/www/html`?

Comment: Could you explain in greater detail?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out the code from git into /var/www/html.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script (bash/python or whatever you like) to copy from /where/your/repo/lives to /var/www/html. You may have to do a git pull to make sure /where/your/repo/lives is up to date, if it's a checked out version of your repo.

Alternatively you could setup the repo on /var/www and do a 'git pull' to update the files.

If you use an online repo they may have a feature to do this for you by ssh'ing into the machine and running the commands for you.